# REST API datetime range not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, date-time

**Background:**

In Sharepoint Online, I'm using the Sharepoint REST API for query a few records based on its creation date (column Created).

I'm using the following variations of the REST query for get the items created in a range of time:

*Variation #1 - has this datetime format: **dd/MM/yyyy**.*

> https:///_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LIST_NAME')/items?&$select=Created&$filter=Created ge '2016-05-01T00:00:00Z' and Created le '2016-05-**04**T00:00:00Z'&$orderby=Created desc

*Variation #2:*

> https:///_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LIST_NAME')/items?&$select=Created&$filter=Created ge '01/05/2016 00:00' and Created le '**04**/05/2016 00:00'&$orderby=Created desc

**Problem:**

I'm waiting that those queries brings me the created data in that lapse of time, But none of them doesn't return any data.

Only when I add one more day to the datetime range, (i.e):

*Variation #1 - has this datetime format: **dd/MM/yyyy**.*

> https:///_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LIST_NAME')/items?&$select=Created&$filter=Created ge '2016-05-01T00:00:00Z' and Created le '2016-05-**05**T00:00:00Z'&$orderby=Created desc

*Variation #2:*

> https:///_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LIST_NAME')/items?&$select=Created&$filter=Created ge '01/05/2016 00:00' and Created le '**05**/05/2016 00:00'&$orderby=Created desc

The query returns me the data that *should* be queried using the datetime range in previous lines.

Here is the results:

> 2016-05-04T22:45:16Z
>
> 2016-05-04T22:36:29Z
>
> 2016-05-04T15:32:59Z
>
> 2016-05-04T15:07:24Z

This is a screenshot which shows the current data available:

[image]

I check [these related questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=rest%20api%20datetime%20is%3Aquestion), but none of them solves my current problem.

**What could be the cause of this situation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the formatting of string value as a valid SharePoint datetime.

[wjervis's comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180735/rest-api-datetime-range-not-working-as-expected#comment189755_180833) is right; I have to adapt my source code for get the selected date "hour and minutes" in my form and using the [toISOString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) method.

So, if I need datetime with the ISO 8601 format; I use the following code:

```
// This is the date that I select in my form: "26/05/2016 17:00".

// I separate the previous string and create a new Date object:
var myDate = new Date(2016, 4, 26, 17, 0);

// With this line, I can use later in the query (using the SharePoint REST API).
var ISO_FormattedDate = myDate.toISOString();
```

The result is:

> 2016-05-26T22:00:00.000Z

And modifying the query as follows:

```
https://<SITE_NAME>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LIST_NAME')/items?&$select=Created&$filter=Created ge '2016-05-26T22:00:00.000Z' and Created le '2016-05-26T23:00:00.000Z'&$orderby=Created desc
```

I finally could get the expected results.

Comment: SharePoint expects the date to be in ISO 8601 format